# Hyperledger Fabric Java SDK client program too slow to terminate

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

I am using the Fabric Java SDK to invoke transactions on Hyperledger Fabric.

I noticed that after submitting a transaction from the client application using Java SDK is much slower than using NodeJs for the program to terminate.

This is what happens in detail: (Chaincode written in Go, client app in Java)

```
Network network = gateway.getNetwork("mychannel");
Contract contract = network.getContract("evidentia");
contract.submitTransaction("createCar", "model", "color", "plate");     
System.out.println("Transaction has been submitted");
```

After the execution of the above code, the client program prints the last line but it doesn't terminate immediately. Although, it waits for a few seconds and then it terminates.

This really slows down the whole process of submitting multiple transactions one by one.

Do you face any similar problems? It happens the same with fabcar example.

Could it be a gRPC issue that Java is waiting to close the connection?

Comment: If you are sending multiple transactions then it is not good practice to have a single program you launch each time you want to send. You should really be looking to have a long running program that does the job of sending transactions. This is because you do not want to be constantly creating gateways and closing them.

Comment: This behavior is also when I send only one transaction, like the code above.

Comment: Well if you are only sending a one off transaction does it really matter then ? if you plan to send a set of transactions then my previous comment applies. I'm not saying that there isn't an issue there, just that it's not necessarily an issue for you. Assuming you ensure the gateway is closed before your program ends then you might want to raise a jira at https://jira.hyperledger.org to report the issue

Comment: Did you try to reproduce? Even if I put gateway.close at the end of the program, it still takes time to terminate. Could it be that it waits for events?

Comment: Not tried to reproduce as I don't do much with java. Suggest you raise a jira issue about it so that someone who works on the gateway sdk could investigate it.

Comment: submitTransaction will block waiting for events that satisfy the chosen event strategy (the strategy defines how how many different events it will wait for). If the default is the same as node.js then it will wait for events from every peer in your org

Comment: This kind of makes sense then. Although the code after the submitTransaction is executed (System.out.println("Transaction has been submitted");)
Then the program hangs for a few seconds.

Comment: It should wait at the submitTransaction call because it should be waiting for the commit events, then it should unblock and print the `Transaction has been submitted`.

Comment: That's not what is happening here. The "Transaction has been submitted" is printed. Is it maybe because of asynchronous calls?

Comment: If it's not waiting at the submit for events then that is another issue as I would expect an error if there was some issue with not being able to wait for events. I really think you need to raise a jira and provide as much detail about your environment and your observations.